# How to get Control from DataTemplate and ControlTemplate ? thinks so much

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

When i define a control in DataTemplate, how to get reference of this control ?

If the control in ControlTemplate of Style , how to get ?

Answer (score 0):

You should instead tell us why you would need to reference a control inside a template.

Consider that the control will be rendered multiple times, so getting a single reference does simply not make any sense.

Comment: i want to change control status, ex: IsEnable or Visibility.

Comment: You should use Data Binding for such properties, or Style Triggers.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach to this is to 'name' the element that you wish to locate via `x:Name="MyElementName"`, you can then use the [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method to locate the names element. If your `DataTemplate` is being used in an `ItemsControl` to render multiple copies of yoru XAML markup, then clearly there will be a number of elements that share this same name. For this reason, there is a concept known as [XAML namescope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189026%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you should read up on this to understand the scope of the name you provide.

If you require a more generic method for searching for elements in the visual tree, try [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), you can use it to query you UI, for example:

```
var itemsFluent = this.Descendants<TextBox>()
                      .Where(i => i.Ancestors().FirstOrDefault() is Grid);
```

The above query will find all `TextBoxs` that have a `Grid` as a direct parent.

Finally, if you can avoid doing any of this, by using databinding, or event bubbling then do so! it is much easier.